# How do I generate a ranndom number or letter with certain rules in python

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to generate a random number but with certain rules. 
The first 11 digits to be `00000001008` so I just made it a string and printed it to the screen then after the string, the next number is a random digit or a letter, so I'm using the random and string module to generate a random digit or letter. After the random generated number I want a set of three 1's so I just printed them as a string like I did with the first eleven values. But here's where I'm getting stuck, after the set of three 1's I want to generate another random number or letter and I can't figure it out, I tried the same line of code as the random variable, with a new variable name and then I tried to concatenate it with the new variable in the print statement and it gives me an error. How can I generate another random number after the three 1's?

```
import random 
import string

    random = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in xrange(1)])

    print ("00000001008")+ random + ("111")
```

## Output

```
00000001008U111
```

## Desired Output

```
00000001008(random)111(random)1(random)
```

## Error

```
import random 
import string

random = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in xrange(1)])
random1 = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in xrange(1)])
print ("00000001008")+ random + ("111") + random1
```

*random1 = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in xrange(1)])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'choice'*

Comment: Please show the code that gave you the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can simply use string formatting and 3 random values

```
import random
import string

def gen():
  return random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)

print('00000001008%s111%s1%s' % (gen(), gen(), gen()))
```

and the only problem why your code is not working is that you named your variable **random**, which made **module random** impossible to access, thus error coming from your random.choice call which now refers to a **string**. Rename your variables to "random_string" and "random_string1" and everything will be just fine.